# Redhat booting into emergency mode after lvreduce /home without umount first - what are my options?

Tags: rhel

I was using lvreduce to reduce the size of /home to assign it to swap. I mistakenly didn’t umount before nor use fsck before and after applying lvreduce(nor did I backup （；＿；）). I restarted the server and now it boots into emergency mode, trying to ctrl-d repeats the prompt. Logging into root works.

Dmesg highlights (AE_NOT_FOUND) as errors but even with using the contents of /proc/mounts in /etc/fstab it does not seem to work. I returned /etc/fstab to it’s original state before that.

What can I do to somehow get back from this?

Answer (score 0):

Not unmounting or running fsck likely were not your issue.  Did you reduce the fs size on the lv before striking it?  (remember if was xfs, shrinking is not an option, at all) If you re-allocated the space already and adjusted swap, you're fs may be partly recoverable via forcing fsck.  If you didn't re-use the space yet, read below.

Boot into recovery mode (or use media to boot with) and chroot to your chroot to your root fs, then execute:

```
# vgcfgrestore --list <your volume group name here>
```

There may be archived metadata taken before the reduce executed.  The tool will let you revert the resize if you haven't re-allocated the space or done anything else to it.  Reducing without extra switches to make it resize the fs would only have changed the lv metadata and not destroyed the data.

Comment: No "maybe" about it - there definitely will be archived metadata, so if the VG capacity was not yet allocated to some different LV, the unfortunate lvreduce will be easy to undo.

Comment: I already assigned that space with lvextend to swap …